# Cmake, undefined symbol: _ZNK5boost6python7objects21py_function_impl_base9max_arityEv

Tags: python, c++, cmake

I have the following error when trying to import a custom c++ module into python.

**undefined symbol: _ZNK5boost6python7objects21py_function_impl_base9max_arityEv**

I have seen several people solve this in the CMake file by adding the following lines

```
target_link_libraries(
    zoo ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Although this does not seem to work for me. Here is the whole cmake file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(zoo)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)

# Trying to get the python files.
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost 1.54.0 COMPONENTS program_options REQUIRED)


set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)


include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} "/usr/include/python2.7")
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})

add_library(zoo SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(zoo ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Any Ideas ?

Comment: have you tried putting python_libraries after boost_libraries? If there's no implicit dependency between them cmake won't order the linker commands correctly on linux.

Comment: yes, that is the original way that I had it, I had the same thought that the order would matter, but it seems to make no difference in this case

Comment: hmm, on second thoughts the missing symbol is a boost symbol. I don't think you've told cmake that you need the boost_python component...

Comment: I have checked countless sites on how to add boost to the project and the find package seems to be the solution, is there a way in cmake that I can tell if this is found or not

Comment: yes but after the COMPONENTS keyword you have only listed program_options. You need python, right? Each component corresponds to a particualr boost library.